# Why owner of symlink to pty device is significant?

Tags: linux, symlink, tty, pty

According to [official documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html) permission and owner of symbolic link is significant if we want to do something with link directly. But if want to, for example, read from file by this link - it doesn't matter. Matter only permissions for target file. But during working with pty devices and links to them I found out that I am unable to read data from pty device by link in one case: if I try to do that as root for symlink in /tmp directory and created by regular user. Steps for reproduce:

1. we need at least one pty from /dev/pts/ folder. If you open at least one terminal there, for example, will be pty like /dev/pts/0. So let use it
2. create symlink to this pty (NOTE: don't use root for this operation):

```sh
ln -s /dev/pts/0 /tmp/link
```

3. after that try use cat with this symlink:

```sh
sudo cat /tmp/link
```

as result you will have error: "permission denied", but if you start this command without sudo - it will work without error

4. change owner of symlink(!)

```sh
sudo chown -h root /tmp/link
```

and try cat again - in this case even with sudo it will work...

Why? Also there is no such problem if link created, for example, in home directory

Comment: If a sym-link behaves differently in `/tmp` than in any other directory, chances are that it is the _sticky_ permission bit.

Comment: In fact, I've just tested it with a regular file, not a PTY and it behaves identically, so the PTY thing is a red-herring.